# How do I disable validation in Web Data Administrator?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run some queries to get rid of XSS in our database using Web Data Administrator but I keep running into this Potentially Dangerous Request crap.

How do I disable validation of the query in Web Data Administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the install directory of web data admin, usually:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Tools\Microsoft SQL Web Data Administrator`

Then in the "Web" folder open the file "QueryDatabase.aspx" and edit the following line:

`<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="QueryDatabase.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="SqlWebAdmin.query" %>`

Add `ValidateRequest="false"` to the end of it like so:

`<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="QueryDatabase.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="SqlWebAdmin.query" ValidateRequest="false" %>`

**NOTE**: THIS IS POTENTIALLY DANGEROUS!! Be Careful!